# Using variables inside react native stylesheets wont recognize the variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I import a color as props.color into my functional component and set it as the state 'tagColor'. When I use tagColor as a value in my stylesheet to set the background color i receive the error 'variable tagColor not found'

How can I use variables inside my stylesheet?

```
const Tag = (props) => {
  
  const [tagColor, setColor] = useState(props.color)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tag} title='tag'>
           
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 25,
    display: 'flex'
  },
  tag: {
    backgroundColor: tagColor,  
}
});

export default Tag;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, of course it doesn't recognize `tagColor`, it's in a different scope. Notice `tagColor` is in the scope of your function component, while the `StyleSheet` is a different scope.

One way to solve this is to directly pass the `backgroundColor` to the `style` prop, like that:

```js
<TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: tagColor}} title="tag">
```

Another way is to define the `tag` class in your `StyleSheet` as a function that receives the color and returns the style, like:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...
  },
  tag: tagColor => ({
    backgroundColor: tagColor,  
})
});
```

And then use it like that:

```js
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.tag(tagColor)} title="tag">
```

I'd go with the first way if you don't have any more styles other than `backgroundColor`. If you need more styles, go with the 2nd method.

Comment: yes I have more styles I just wrote the code that way for simplicity. I will try the second method thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If tagColor is the only style you wish to apply you can do this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: tagColor }} title='tag'>
```

If you want to apply tagColor and also apply styles from a style sheet (EG container) you could put both inside an array like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: tagColor }]} title='tag'>
```